# Element Not Interactable / Element not clickable

Tags: java, selenium, selenium-webdriver, selenium-chromedriver, cucumber

I tried using explicit wait, ExpectedConditions.elementToBeClickable and waitForVisibleElement but it ends up with time out and waiting for element to be clickable.

I also tried getting different locators (different div). Here is my code (and the ones I tried)

```
public void setSystemInformationSection() throws Exception {

        scrollPageDownBy800();
        
        //wait.until(ExpectedConditions.elementToBeClickable(INVERTERMANUFACTURERDRPDWN));
        //click(INVERTERMANUFACTURERDRPDWN, "INVERTERMANUFACTURERDRPDWN;");
        
        
        //click(INVERTERMANUFACTURERDRPDWN, "INVERTERMANUFACTURERDRPDWN;");
        //waitForVisibleElement(driver, SMACORE1OPTION); click(SMACORE1OPTION,"SMACORE1OPTION");
                

        Boolean wait = new WebDriverWait(driver,20).until(ExpectedConditions.invisibilityOfElementLocated(By.xpath("//*[@id=\"SMA - Core1\"]")));
        jse.executeScript("arguments[0].click()", INVERTERMANUFACTURERDRPDWN);
        //waitForVisibleElement(driver, SMACORE1OPTION);
        jse.executeScript("arguments[0].click()", SMACORE1OPTION);
}
```

Other dropdowns I tried worked fine with the last snippet of code (the ones not commented out)

I tried this with a different dropdown and it worked okay

```
    public void setCommercialDealType() throws Exception {
        Boolean wait = new WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(ExpectedConditions.invisibilityOfElementLocated(By.xpath("/html/body/app-root/ng-component/commercial-create-account/main/section[2]/opportunity-information/form/div[2]/div[1]/sp-dropdown/div/div/div[2]/ul/li[2]")));
        jse.executeScript("arguments[0].click()", COMMERCIALDEALTYPEDROPDOWN);
        waitForVisibleElement(driver, COMMERCIALHELIXPPA);
        jse.executeScript("arguments[0].click()", COMMERCIALHELIXPPA);
    }
```

When I try to check with isEnabled or isDisplayed, it gives TimeOut error. I'm stuck.

Comment: Can you share the url of the page that you are trying to automate, or you can add the HTML code of the portion of the page that you are trying to automate in the question above.

Answer (score 1):

Sometimes an element is visible or clickable to you, but divs or spans (or other elements) are hiding it from Selenium perspective.
To overcome this:

1. First you find an element by ID, xpath or Css expression.
2. Try to move to the element (focus on it) using Selenium and then click it.
3. If step 2 failed - just do element.click
4. if step 3 failed - do a hard click using javaScript:

Code example:

```
 public void clickLastFoundElement() {        
    try {
        Actions builder = new Actions(browser);
        builder.moveToElement(lastFoundElement).click().build().perform();
    } catch (ElementNotInteractableException x1) {
        try {
            lastFoundElement.click();
        }
        catch (Exception x2) {
            hardClickElement();
        }
    }
}

private void hardClickElement() {
    JavascriptExecutor executor = (JavascriptExecutor) browser;
    executor.executeScript("arguments[0].click();", lastFoundElement);      
}
```

Comment: I actually did all that, the number 4 passes the test but in actuality, it does not click anything.

Comment: So the element is not really clickable, it is disabled.

Comment: It is clickable. I discovered something when testing things, when I select an option in the above page, the dropdown becomes unclickable. But when I leave it to the default option, it clicks the element. Maybe the xpath moves? I'm really lost.

Comment: Don't wait for element to be invisible, wait for it to be presence or clickable. If some thing fails - wrap it in try and catch block. In the catch block try to find the element again, it may the the page changed greatly and with it the DOM...

Comment: I found the problem. 2 elements has the same xpaths. Adding '[2]' does not work, any tips?

Comment: Read about Css selectors and xpath selectors. You can find an element by text inside it like this (as xpath): //div[contains(text(),'Your text here')]. Try to so what differ the elements from one another